# many eclipse projects into one hg repository

Tags: eclipse, mercurial

I have multiple eclipse projects that are tightly related. I want to add them in a mercurial repo (repos).

**Option1:**
Repo per project - too many repos and then I loose my ability to group projects because all projects are repos.

**Option2:**
Multiple projects in one repo as folders.
First, eclipse's plugin cannot add many project into one repo ([this tutorial fails for me](https://ekkescorner.wordpress.com/blog-series/git-mercurial/workflow-create-multi-project-repositories-hg/), there aren't many tutorials on the subject, I guess I can do this from the command line).
Also I cannot pull/push per project. I have to perform this operation per repo. I miss SVN in this regard.

**Option3:**
[mercurial forest](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ForestExtension) - no longer actively supported.

**Option4:**
[Subrepository](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository?action=show&redirect=subrepos) - feature of last resort.

What is the best practice?

It looks like a simple case like this doesn't have a straightforward answer. Is mercurial actively developed?

Answer (score 1):

Second question first: Mercurial **is** actively developed.  [Here's the source update log.](http://selenic.com/hg)

Option 2 is your best bet.  Like the guide you linked to shows, the repository folder (with the .hg folder inside of it...'n-projects-ws-repo' in this example) means that this folder--and every file and folder in this folder structure--is part of the repository.  The diagram they show is two subfolders called org.ekkescorner.one and org.ekkescorner.two.  These are two projects under the repo called 'n-projects-ws-repo'.

Comment: Yeah, but it fails for a current eclipse ide. I just doesn't work. I don't remember what doesn't work, but I couldn't do it. The plugin kind of sucks :)